# Is CGAffineTransform's document is wrong?

Tags: iphone, rotation, cgaffinetransform

The document says:

The angle, in radians, by which to rotate the affine transform. In iOS, a positive value specifies counterclockwise rotation and a negative value specifies clockwise rotation.

But in my experiment, I conclude these:

```
YourView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( positive value );
```

will rotate the view clockwise, and

```
YourView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( Negative value );
```

will rotate the view counterclockwise,

Does those contradict with each other? I mean, in a flipped coordinate system, like this:

[image]

a positive angle represents a clockwise rotation, but the documents say "In iOS, a positive value specifies counterclockwise rotation." So i think it's contradictive. Is the document wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing, since you don't provide enough code, that you are doing this in a `UIKit` view. `UIKit` flips the coordinate system before calling `drawRect` giving the impression that the rotation is happening in the wrong direction.

The `CoreGraphics` coordinate system is 1st quadrant, that is, (0,0) is the lower-left corner, `UIKit` is 4th quadrant with (0,0) in the top-left.

If you unflip the coordinate system all will be well.